# Which is more correct to calculate least squares (errors) during nonlinear curve fitting, calculating after transformation or in the original form?

Tags: regression, least-squares, curve-fitting, total-least-squares

I am studying curve fitting and linear regression. I am supposed to find a and b in the equation $$
P=ae^{bh}
$$
so I transformed it to
$$
lnP=ln a +bh
$$
then
$$
Y=c+bX
$$
after that I solved it to get (after converting my points from (h,P) to (h,lnP)) $$a=e^{c} , b$$ now I have to find $$R , TSS , RSS$$ the problem is when i calulate them using the exponential form i get completely different numbers from the linear one (as i used different point), which one should I use or how to get R,TSS,RSS correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is little dispute as to the accuracy of the prediction intervals, as expressed in a natural log format, assuming the underlying assumptions for the Least-Squares are met (including the error terms are random independent samplings from a log-normal density which upon applying a log transform are normal).

With the interval expressed in the natural logs (base e), however, the issue may arise as to the meaning of the interval upon rising to the power of e. In this event, assuming the original model error terms where, in fact, lognormal, then the exponential of the sample mean of logs actually relates to the geometric or multiplicative mean of the log-normal distribution, which is a sample estimate for the median of the log-normal (and not its mean, [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)).